# selecting rows without using 'not in' clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, subquery, case

I have a table like this:

```
+----+----------+
| ID |    WA    |
+----+----------+
|124 | benefit  |
|124 | ordane   |
|124 | military |
|124 | para     |
|125 | benefit  |
|126 | benefit  |
|126 | ordane   |
|127 | benefit  |
|127 | ordane   |
|127 | military |
|128 | benefit  |
+----+----------+
```

I wanted those ID's with WA = 'benefit' and  exclude those ID's with WA = 'ordane'.  I want to avoid `not in`, `not exists` and `except`.  I tried with `CASE` statement but didn't get it. Is there any other way? Thanks!

Comment: Is this asked to you in an interview?

Answer (score 3):

Just use post aggregation filtering with HAVING

```
SELECT id FROM t GROUP BY id 
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN WA='benefit' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)>0
AND SUM(CASE WHEN WA='ordane' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)=0
```

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen You query evaluates for each row thats why it wont work,create a fiddle if you think I`m wrong